# Recycler view se sobrepone con todos los fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, navigation-drawer

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el cual mando a llamar todos mis registros en mysql el cual me lo muestra mediante un recycler view al momento de ejecutar la aplicacion me muestra todo bien pero al moverme a un fragment diferente me sigue mostrando el recycler view y no se a que se deba

Codigo del Navigation Drawer

```
package com.codeseasy.examples.loginregister;

import static com.codeseasy.examples.loginregister.databinding.NavigationDrawerBinding.inflate;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class NavigationDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etBuscador;
    RecyclerView rvLista;
    AdaptadorUsuarios adaptador;
    List<Usuario> listaUsuarios;

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        com.codeseasy.examples.loginregister.databinding.NavigationDrawerBinding binding = inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow, R.id.recyclerFragment)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        etBuscador = findViewById(R.id.etBuscador);
        etBuscador.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                filtrar(s.toString());
            }
        });

        rvLista = findViewById(R.id.rvLista);
        rvLista.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));

        listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();

        obtenerUsuarios();

        adaptador = new AdaptadorUsuarios(NavigationDrawer.this, listaUsuarios);
        rvLista.setAdapter(adaptador);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    public void obtenerUsuarios() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getResources().getString(R.string.URL_USUARIOS),
                response -> {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Usuarios");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            listaUsuarios.add(
                                    new Usuario(
                                            jsonObject1.getString("idUsuario"),
                                            jsonObject1.getString("nombre"),
                                            jsonObject1.getString("telefono"),
                                            jsonObject1.getString("email"),
                                            jsonObject1.getString("usuario"),
                                            jsonObject1.getString("contrasena")

                                    )
                            );
                        }

                        adaptador = new AdaptadorUsuarios(NavigationDrawer.this, listaUsuarios);
                        rvLista.setAdapter(adaptador);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace
        );

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void filtrar(String texto) {
        ArrayList<Usuario> filtrarLista = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Usuario usuario : listaUsuarios) {
            if(usuario.getNombre().toLowerCase().contains(texto.toLowerCase())) {
                filtrarLista.add(usuario);
            }
        }

        adaptador.filtrar(filtrarLista);
    }


}
```

Codigo xml del Navigation Drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_main"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etBuscador"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Buscar"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvLista"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etBuscador" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Codigo Content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Codigo app_bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawer">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Al ejecutar el proyecto asi se ve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al moverme a otro fragment mediante el menu se sigue mostrando el recycler view

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrian orientar o ayudarme a ver mi error ya lo intente poniendo el recycler view en el content y en el app_bar pero si lo hago asi me deja de funcionar el menu y no cambia entre fragments

Gracias

Comment: El `RecyclerView` se sigue mostrando porque está en el layout del `Activity` que contiene a tus fragments. Lo que tendrías que hacer es colocarlo en el `fragment` correspondiente. Si falla al hacer ese cambio entonces tendrías que revisar tu código para entender porque al mover el `RecyclerView` deja de funcionar tu menu. Otra alternativa sería ocultarlo, dependiendo de que `fragment` este visible, pero sería más complicado.

Comment: Gracias, si tenia un problema con unos parametros al migrarlo a fragment pero ya pude solucionarlo gracias